# jQuery UI Autocomplete scroll to top if type more text

Tags: jquery-ui, scroll, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a jQuery autocomplete working against my testbox just fine except when I type, get a set of resultss, scroll down a bit, then type more words (new result) the new result stays scrolled to the same poistion as the old result set.

Is there an easy way that I am missing to force the autocmplete result list to scroll to top prior to returning new results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope that the usage `$('.ui-menu').scrollTop(0);` inside of `search` will solve your problem. The following code seams me even better:

```
$("#myinput").autocomplete({
    // ... other parameters which you use
    search: function () {
        $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.element.scrollTop(0);
    }
});
```

Comment: Than you, this pointed me in the right direction.  I put `$('ul.ui-autocomplete').scrollTop(0);' in the 'source:'  just before the ajax call.

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss: You are welcome! But I don't understand why `$('ul.ui-autocomplete')` selector is better which search page for *any* autocomplete menus? The `$(this).data("autocomplete").menu.element` inside of events like `search`, `close` and so on gives you exactly the menu which you need. Where you see the advantage?

Comment: The syntax you provided gave an error on the page load in the `source:` and I did not have a `search:` or `close` etc, so I did it this way.

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss: It sound strange. I use mostly `autocomplete` with the URL in the `source`, but in [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ToolbarSearchWithAutocomplete.htm) it is as an array of strings. If you type "a" for example in the first input field ('Name') the menu will displayed and both `search` and `close` works. I just commented the `alert` in the `search` event to allow the menu been seen. What kind of `source` you use, so that `search` and `close` not fire? It's more strange that you have an error on the **page loading**. Which code fragment you use for `autocomplete`?

Comment: I think the issue was I did not have either `search:` or `close:` in place in my code.  I added the search and it seems to work as you pointed out, and likely a better spot for that scroll than the source with the ajax anyway.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss: You are welcome! Sometime I study myself something new from the people for which I wrote my answer. So I just try to bring all things to the end and understand why something do not works like I think.